# In ansible tower, how to copy files from another project to target servers?

Tags: ansible-tower

I have 2 repos created in bitbucket:

repo A - public to end users to update configuration files

repo B - private, a playbook to sync configurations files (copy module)

I synced both of the repos to Ansible Tower as 2 projects: project A and B, then added an inventory sourced from repo B's inventory file.

Template is working as expected except copying the files of project B.

May I know how could I set the src parameter in copy module of my playbook so that it could copy all of the config files in project A to target servers in inventory?

Try to find a way to copy files from other project in Ansible Tower.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Git module helped me solve the issue.